# How to auto delete the children if parent is removed or deleted?

Tags: typescript, express, typeorm

I have the following entity. How can I auto delete the childCategories if the parent category is deleted using category repository's delete or remove?

```js
import { UserEntity } from '@entities/user.entity';
import { Entity, Column, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Relation, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class CategoryEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false, unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  icon: string;

  @ManyToOne(Type => UserEntity, user => user.categories)
  user: Relation<UserEntity>;

  @ManyToOne(type => CategoryEntity, category => category.childCategories, {
    createForeignKeyConstraints: false,
  })
  parentCategory: CategoryEntity;

  @OneToMany(type => CategoryEntity, category => category.parentCategory)
  childCategories: CategoryEntity[];
}
```

Actually, I tried delete the category by id, the category is deleted but it's children data still remain in the database.

Comment: Does adding `onDelete: "CASCADE",` below `createForeignKeyConstraints: false,` work?

Comment: Yes, I try adding onDelete: "CASCADE" on parentCategory, the child deletion are working as expected. Thanks a lot @zouabi

Comment: You're welcome! Will post an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add an `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` to the parent relationship.

```
  @ManyToOne(type => CategoryEntity, category => category.childCategories, {
    createForeignKeyConstraints: false,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  parentCategory: CategoryEntity;
```

References:

- [Comment on "Cannot cascade deletion along one-to-many relations"](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1913#issuecomment-743129562)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use cascades for this work. Please add the following options object to your OneToMany annotation:

```js
  @OneToMany(type => CategoryEntity, category => category.parentCategory, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
  childCategories: CategoryEntity[];
```

documentation for further reading can be found [here](https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/cascade-delete-in-typeorm/)

Comment: Thanks, Goran. But for me, I added at the parent instead of child like that
@ManyToOne(type => CategoryEntity, category => category.childCategories, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  parentCategory: CategoryEntity;

And now working as expected.

BTW what is the difference between adding onDelete CASCADE to child and parent?